# invalid username/password; logon denied with kerberos authentication

Tags: oracle, authentication, active-directory, kerberos

**I am attempting to configure Oracle with Kerberos. I have completed all of the necessary configurations and have obtained a ticket. However, when I run `SQLPlus /@ORCL`, I receive the following error:**

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sqlplus /@ORCL
 
SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Feb 21 05:42:04 2024
Version 21.3.0.0.0
 
Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle. All rights reserved.
 
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

**I am using a Windows machine that acts as both a server and a client. Below are all the details.**

[okinit testuser]

```
C:\Users\Administrator>sqlplus /@ORCL

SQL*Plus: Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on Wed Feb 21 05:42:04 2024
Version 21.3.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2021, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

okinit

```
    C:\Users\Administrator>okinit testuser

Kerberos Utilities for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 21-FEB-2024 05:40:30

Copyright (c) 1996, 2021 Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Configuration file : C:\Windows\krb5.ini.
Password for testuser@EXAMPLE.COM:
```

[oklist]

```
    C:\Users\Administrator>oklist

Kerberos Utilities for 64-bit Windows: Version 21.0.0.0.0 - Production on 21-FEB-2024 05:40:49

Copyright (c) 1996, 2021 Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Configuration file : C:\Windows\krb5.ini.
Ticket cache: FILE:C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\kerberos\krb5cache
Default principal: testuser@EXAMPLE.COM

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
02/21/24 05:40:33  02/21/24 15:40:33  krbtgt/EXAMPLE.COM@EXAMPLE.COM
        renew until 02/22/24 05:40:30
```

[sqlnet.ora file]

```
    SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (KERBEROS5, KERBEROS5PRE)
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_KEYTAB = C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\keytab\keyfile.keytab
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CC_NAME = C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\kerberos\krb5cache
SQLNET.KERBEROS5_CONF = C:\Windows\krb5.ini
SQLNET.FALLBACK_AUTHENTICATION = TRUE
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_KERBEROS5_SERVICE = ORCL
```

[krb5.ini]

```
    libdefaults]
    default_realm = EXAMPLE.COM
    forwardable = true
    clockskew = 6000
    passwd_check_s_address = false
 

[realms]
    EXAMPLE.COM = {
                kdc = hostname.EXAMPLE.COM
        admin_server = hostname.EXAMPLE.COM
                default_domain = EXAMPLE.COM
        }

[domain_realm] 
    .EXAMPLE.COM = EXAMPLE.COM
    EXAMPLE.COM = EXAMPLE.COM
    .example.com= EXAMPLE.COM
    example.com = EXAMPLE.COM
```

[keytab generation cmd]

```
ktpass /princ ORCL/hostname.example.com@EXAMPLE.COM /mapuser testuser@EXAMPLE.COM /crypto ALL /ptype KRB5_NT_PRINCIPAL /out C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\keytab\keyfile.keytab /pass password1
```

Comment: When you're on Windows you should not need to use ktpass, or a keytab file.
You should set KERBEROS5_CC_NAME to a plugin which will withdraw kerberos ticket from SSPI cache.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/77725413/836215

Comment: Hello @ibre5041 , I am new to database authentication and I want to configure Kerberos authentication for Oracle. However, I am unable to find any documents that provide me with proper steps to set this up. Can you please send me the reference files of sqlnet.ora, krb5.ini, etc. if you have them? 
Thank you so much for replying.